# What is the best place to ask for help, and tips, on designing a web application?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'm new to web applications, and have some broad questions about designing a back end, and model view controllers. Where is the best place to ask?

Comment: Thanks for the link! unfortunately I checked and the design tag is off topic, also there are no tags for project-planning. I'm not sure my question is specific enough for that board.

Comment: Relevant: https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6367/218574 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100036/318307

Comment: Yeah, the descriptor for the design tag is "Designing, developing, & programming web applications is off-topic for webApps."

My question is a general one about what technologies, frameworks, and libraries to consider when planning a web application. I am building a simple game, that will need to store user accounts, about 40 images, and sound files. Also MVC will be used to manage what the user sees. But the JavaScript ecosystem is so vast I don't know where to start. 

Thanks for your help @catija!

Comment: @Ollie hold off on burning websites for a few days untill people had time to voice their opinions on that burnination request.

Comment: @Luuklag I was going to, I just knocked off the obviously unnecessary ones.

Answer (score 3):

In general Stack Exchange sites are designed for focused Q&A, and so any broad questions risk being closed as Too Broad.

Asking broad questions may be OK to do in some chat rooms but observe what they allow before posting in one.

Comment: Do you know of any sites where I could ask a more broad question?

Comment: I think progress in any project is best made by seeking answers to a series of focussed questions so I can't recall ever looking to ask a broad one. I think answers to broad questions are probably best found using Google searches.